# PHPUnit: using test suites the old way without frameworks and stuff

Tags: php, phpunit

I've been using PHPUnit for several years in my projects, and I don't utilize Composer, XML, frameworks, or similar tools.

My development process involves a script running on a secondary Konsole window (on a secondary display) with inotifywait. The script looks like this:

```
inotifywait --format %w%f -m -q -r -e close_write src tests _public  | \
while read CUAL ; do
    clear
    phpunit --stop-on-failure --fail-on-warning   --disallow-test-output --no-configuration  --no-extensions   --columns 80 --color ./tests/testsSuite.php

    echo Pruebas : $? $(date +"%Y %m %d %T")  >>$log
    echo 
    echo -n "cant veces ejecutado hoy: "
    wc -l $log  | egrep "^[0-9]*" -o
done
```

This script runs continuously until I close my development session. It waits for a file to be modified by my IDE (Netbeans) and then fires the unit tests (I got this idea from Kent Beck's video).

The testsSuite.php file looks like this:

```
require_once "./tests/fuentes_tests.php";

use \PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite;

class testsSuite extends TestSuite {

    public function __construct() {

        $this->setName( self::class );

//        // microtests
        $this->addTestSuite( basico_Test::class );
        $this->addTestSuite( etc_Test::class );
        
    }

    public static function suite() {
        return new self();
    }

}
```

This has been the structure of my test suites for about a decade, with the exception that namespaces were added at some point to shrink class names.

While it runs fine under PHPUnit 9, under versions 10 and above, it gives this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot override final method PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite::__construct() in /var/www/htdocs/botmaker/tests/testsSuite.php on line 38

cant veces ejecutado hoy: 44
^C
rudy@rudy:~/37sur/botmaker$
```

Given the situation, I'm considering downloading the source code and exploring potential solutions myself. However, before I delve into that, I wanted to know if there's another approach not mentioned by PHPUnit's documentation.

Edit: the real reason why I want to avoid using XML or composer is that I find it a lot more easy to disable specific tests or group them as I like, all I have to do is to comment lines of code. Also it allows me to group tests under methods on the derived class, ie: real_tests() which talks to the database.

unfortunately the old documentation stating this way of doing a test suite is mostly gone. the closest thing I found so far is [this](https://phpunit.de/manual/2.3/en/api.html#api.testsuite)

I stick to phpunit because I do not know if there's an alternative which provides code coverage analysis. Been searching for it but no luck so far.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot override final method PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite::__construct()

You're trying to override `__construct()` but that is now a `final` class, which can't be overridden. You should not be extending `__construct()` yourself, even in versions prior to 10. It has only became actually enforced in 10.

Instead, use one of:

```php
public function setUp(): void
{
    // this code gets run before each test method
}
```

```php
public static function setUpBeforeClass(): void
{
    // this code gets run once when the class is instantiated
}
```

Note that `setUpBeforeClass()` is static, so you'd have to change your code somewhat to avoid `$this` in your current constructor.

Comment: ty for your comment. please note that I extending TestSuite, not TestCase. Will try your suggestion anyway.

Comment: Ah yes OK, apologies, I did not notice that. Still, __construct() is final for that class as well, so you can not extend it at all.

Comment: Can't you just define your suites in the `phpunit.xml` file?

Comment: yes, thanks you, I do understand that, but I want to know if there's another way, as long as I do not have to implement XML and modify xml or use composer as proposed by documentation. I find this way flexible, that's why I will insist on this.